# Mapping multiple Models to ViewModel with Automapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, viewmodel

Let's say I have two models that my View requires information from. I am using automapper to map parts of each model into a single ViewModel. Is this good practice? If not, what other ways can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put a little more code if you can.  But why do you need to use automapper for this?  Should be straight forward I think.

```
public class ModelA
{
    [stuff via automapper?]
}
public class ModelB
{
    [stuff via automapper?]
}
public class HappyViewModel
{
    public ModelA ModelA { get; set; }
    public ModelB ModelB { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new HappyViewModel();
    model.ModelA = [populate me]
    model.ModelB = [populate me]
    return View(model)
}
```

View

```
@model HappyViewModel
Model.ModelA.[stuff]
Model.ModelB.[stuff]
```