# Create view from view model to show data from two table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I want to create a "Create view" to enter information for both employee and address from a single page... I have my employemodel and my addressmodel. I am creating an EmployeeViewModel like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace gpos.Models
{
    public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        public EmployeeModel NewEmployeViewModel { get; set; }
        public AddressModel NewAddressViewModel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

now in my controller create action I want to generate a view to show data from both employee and address... I know I must use the viewModel but still not clear for me. I would really appreciate some help, tutorial reference...

Thank you so much

Comment: Personally, I like to flatten my viewmodel and not have nested classes. So I would have properties like EmployeeName, EmployeeCity, etc. at the root level. So your GET flattens it out and your POST gathers. AutoMapper was designed specifically for this use case, although you can roll your own. You can also do it the way you have it above - you would just do @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.NewEmployeeViewModel.EmployeeName) etc. One example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512091/mapping-multiple-models-to-viewmodel-with-automapper)

Comment: Thank you! Just learning about AutoMapper.